# Can I predict a target value (event) that happens at the same time when a data record is written?

Tags: classification

I do have difficulty to decide whether or not my classification approach makes sense.

My data set contains sensor data (voltages, state of charge, temperatures, etc.) from different machines. Every machine writes a record after every run. Runs are of different lengths and range from a few seconds up to hours.

Every record also contains a flag that indicates if a malfunction occured. My goal is to predict this malfunction.

How do I choose my target variable? It doesn't make sense to choose the flag because every future record will already contain this flag. Once a record is written it is already too late to predict a malfunction.

I had the idea to calculate some kind of offset to the malfunction event. So I can try to predict if a malfunction occurs in the following run of the machine.

```
Time, Var1, Var2, Var3, Malfunction, *Malfunction Next Run*
12:00, X, X, X, 0, 0
12:01, X, X, X, 0, 0
12:05, X, X, X, 0, 1
12:25, X, X, X, 1, 0
```

Does this make any sense? If the third record is a perfectly fine run like the first two my classification model won't be able to predict the malfunction accurately.

How would you address this problem?

Comment: This is a very reasonable approach. You presumably want to predict malfunctions in time to do something about them.